# returning 2 json values from firebase but one of them is always null? Why?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm not an experienced android app developer this only my first app, with that said here is my problem. I am taking the value of "company_name" from the manager's Json area by calling the dataSnapshot from addListenerForSingleValueEvent and than putting the value into the the recipient's Json area(I'm also storing the manager's id "manager_id" in the recipient's Json area), so far that works OK. The problem now is reading the value "company_name" from the recipient's area to populate it in a list using firebaseUI, for some rason I can't figure out why "manager_id" is returned as as a string but "company_name" is null. Here is the code:
Getting the value for the "company_name":

```
mManagersCompany.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            companyName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Storing it in the recipient's area:

```
Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
info.put("company_name", companyName);
info.put("manager_id", manager_id);
mListOfManagers.push().updateChildren(info);
```

object:

```
public class CompanyItem {
private String company_name;
private String manager_id;

public CompanyItem(){}

public CompanyItem(String company_name, String manager_id){
    this.company_name = company_name;
    this.manager_id = manager_id;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return company_name;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.company_name = companyName;
}

public String getManager_id() {
    return manager_id;
}

public void setManager_id(String manager_id_entering) {
    this.manager_id = manager_id_entering;
}
```

}

retrieve "manager_id" and "company_name" with populateViewHolder of firebaseUI:

```
@Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(CompanyViewHolder viewHolder, CompanyItem model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.hText.setText(model.getCompanyName());
                    viewHolder.mText.setText(model.getManager_id());
                }
```

Here is part of the recipient's Json in firebase database:

```
{  "-KYVoYBRD4UEBL6GYKD_" : 
    {
    "company_name" : "Dude Company",
    "manager_id" : "a1b2c3d4"
    }
}
```

Why does it return "a1b2c3d4" for the "manager_id" but null for "company_name"? I tried so many different things but I wasn't successful, and I searched through stackoverflow for an answer but couldn't find one that is close to my problem. Can anyone help please?

Comment: change your setter/getter for `company_name` to match the format of `manager_id`

Comment: Please update your question showing the updated code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, oh my! you were right I changed getCompanyName() to getCompany_name() and that worked for some reason I still don't understand, I thought the method name didn't really matter. But either way I feel so stupid and I thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment

change your setter/getter for company_name to match the format of manager_id –

for example

`getCompanyName()` to `getCompany_name()`